How to remove global npm packge?
I'm struggling with angular versions and packages.
I've been trying to uninstall angular/cli but not to avail.
Steps

Checking global packages (visible: @angular/cli)

> npm ls -g --depth=0

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @angular/cli@9.0.6
`-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.18.1


Uninstalling @angular/cli using the -g flag with the uninstall command - Why not working?

> npm uninstall -g @angular/cli@9.0.6

up to date in 252ms


Checking global packages (visible: @angular/cli) --> Removal unsuccessful

> npm ls -g --depth=0

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @angular/cli@9.0.6
`-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.18.1


Checks the integrity of the NPM cache

> npm cache verify

Cache verified and compressed (~\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache)
Content verified: 639 (25747808 bytes)
Index entries: 639
Finished in 1.829s


Checking global packages (visible: @angular/cli) --> Removal unsuccessful

> npm ls -g --depth=0

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @angular/cli@9.0.6
`-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.18.1

It seems I can't get rid of this package.

The file maybe locked. Restart your machine to ensure nothing is locking it. Then manually go into those folders and remove the file from Roaming and the cache folder. Also remove your local node_modules folder. Reinstall and try again

Does this answer your question? How to uninstall/upgrade Angular CLI?

Uninstalling global packages (docs.npmjs.com)

I believe your question was already answered here: How to uninstall/upgrade Angular CLI?
The solution seems to be running npm uninstall -g @angular/cli without specifying the version, and then npm cache clean --force to clear the cache

Source: Uninstalling global packages (docs.npmjs.com)

To uninstall an unscoped global package, on the command line, use the uninstall command with the -g flag. Include the scope if the package is scoped.
Unscoped package
npm uninstall -g <package_name>

Scoped package
npm uninstall -g <@scope/package_name>

Example
For example, to uninstall a package called jshint, run:
npm uninstall -g jshint


So, as it is also clearly visible from the documentation, there is no need to specify a version number when uninstalling. This is logical too, since only one specific version can be installed from one package, so why should it be necessary to specify? Simply omit the version number for uninstallation.
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

